# 'Like' a link via Graph API in Android

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

does anyone know if it is possible to 'like' a not-facebook link via the Graph API?

For Example, I want to like the link

https://stackoverflow.com/

via my app.

Do I have to post this link and 'like' my post afterwards or is there also a direct way?

I'm thankful for any answer that helps! :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The graph api does allow you to like a graph object (see [Graph API Docs / Publishing](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/#publishing)) using:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/OBJECT_ID/likes
```

However the graph object must have an existing *likes* connection - and there's currently no way of creating such a connection via the graph api.

But if the like connection already exists you can get the pages graph object id using FQL:

```
SELECT id FROM object_url WHERE url='http://youtargeturl.lnk'
```

Comment: Thank you very much. So instead of 'liking' I will post the url as link with a preview image. I think that's better.

Answer (score 0):

Now in sdk3 you use open graph api

```
private void likeStory() {
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

    if (session != null){

        // Check for publish permissions    

        Request.Callback callback= new Request.Callback() {
            public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                if (response!=null){
                    Log.d("Lavoro", "response"+response.toString());

                    JSONObject graphResponse=null;


                    if (response.getGraphObject()!=null){
                        graphResponse = response.getGraphObject()
                            .getInnerJSONObject();
                        try {
                            postId = graphResponse.getString("id");
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }                       


                    FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
                    if (error != null) {
                        Toast.makeText(activity, error.getErrorMessage()+error.getErrorCode(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        buttonFacebookLike.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(activity, postId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        buttonFacebookLike.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        updateLike();
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        Log.d("Lavoro", "postId like"+postId);
        Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
        postParams.putString("object", "URL TO LIKE");

         Request request = new Request(session, "me/og.likes", postParams, HttpMethod.POST, callback);
        Log.d("Lavoro", "request"+request.toString());

       // Request request = new Request(session, postId+"/comments", postParams, 
       //         HttpMethod.POST, callback);
        RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
        task.execute();
    }
}
```